# MYSQL Stored procedure throwing Error [1644] [45000]: Variable MESSAGE_TEXT can't be set to the value of NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Every time i execute mysql stored procedure i getting **SQL Error [1644] [45000]: Variable 'MESSAGE_TEXT' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'**

To understand what exact i tried all the option but no luck

Issue :

1. Execute stored procedure first time - Success
2. Execute stored procedure second time - Error

Temp Workaround :

1. Execute stored procedure first time - Success
2. Put same blank space in non code area and save
3. Execute stored procedure - Success

I am not getting what exactly the issue and how to resolve it, if anyone can help will be appriciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  OrderStatusInsert(IN _json JSON)
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE  _tempDocNo varchar(50);
    DECLARE _Flag VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE _AWBNo VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE _FirstActionDate VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE _DriverId VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE _RunsheetNo varchar(100);
    DECLARE _InsertedBy INT;
    DECLARE _ShelveId VARCHAR(45); 
    DECLARE _ShelveCode VARCHAR(45); 
    DECLARE _LocationCode  VARCHAR(20); 
    DECLARE _VehicleNo  VARCHAR(25); 
    DECLARE _DriverDetail VARCHAR(200); 
    DECLARE _LineCount INT default 0;
    DECLARE _ErrorMessage VARCHAR(500) ; 
    DECLARE _UniqueId VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s');
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN    
        GET  DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION  1 _ErrorMessage = Message_Text;      
        ROLLBACK; 
        SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
        INSERT INTO SqlExceptionData(SPName,ErrorMessage,Parameters,InsertedOn,InsertedBy)
        VALUES ('OrderStatusInsert',_ErrorMessage,_json,NOW(),'SYSTEM');
         
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _ErrorMessage; 
    END;    
     
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempDRSJson;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempDRSJson 
    SELECT   JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_json,'$.Flag')) as Flag
        ,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_json,'$.RunsheetNo'))as RunsheetNo
        ,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_json,'$.LocationCode')) as LocationCode
        ,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_json,'$.VehicleNo')) as VehicleNo
        ,IFNULL(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_json,'$.DriverId')),0)  as DriverId
        ,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_json,'$.AWBNo'))  as AWBNo
        ,IFNULL(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_json,'$.InsertedBy')),0)  as InsertedBy
    ;
    SELECT Flag, RunsheetNo, InsertedBy, DriverId INTO _Flag, _RunsheetNo, _InsertedBy, _DriverId FROM tempDRSJson ;
       
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempDRS;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempDRS (
    SRNO int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
    ,Id int(11)
    ,RunsheetNo  varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,AWBNo varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,City varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,DriverId varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,DriverName varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,Status varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,DriverPhoneNo varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,PaymentMethod varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,CollectableAmount INT default 0
    ,FacilityAddress varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,PhoneNumber1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,Consignee varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,ConsigneeAddress1 varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,Latitude varchar(50) DEFAULT '0'
    ,Longitude varchar(50) DEFAULT '0'
    ,InsertedOn varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,InsertedBy varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,VehicleNo varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,LocationCode varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL 
    ,PRIMARY KEY (SRNO),
    KEY IDX_RunsheetNo (RunsheetNo) ); 
 
    IF (UPPER(_Flag)='INSERTLINE') THEN
    BEGIN   
          
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM LocationMaster  LM INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.LocationCode=LM.LocationCode LIMIT 1  ) THEN 
            BEGIN 
                SET _ErrorMessage = CONCAT('Invalid location') ; 
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _ErrorMessage; 
            END; 
            ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM ShipmentData SD INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.AWBNo=SD.AWBNo LIMIT 1  ) THEN 
            BEGIN 
                SET _ErrorMessage =  'Invalid box'  ; 
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _ErrorMessage; 
            END; 
            ELSE IF(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM DRSLine DL INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.AWBNo=DL.AWBNo AND DL.DriverId != IFNULL(TR.DriverId,0)) THEN
            BEGIN  
                SELECT CONCAT('Box: ',  TR.AWBNo, ' is already scanned by driver : ', DM.Name , ' in RunsheetNo: ', DL.RunsheetNo)
                INTO  _ErrorMessage 
                FROM DRSLine DL INNER JOIN UserMaster DM ON DL.DriverId = DM.Id
                INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.AWBNo=DL.AWBNo  
                AND DL.DriverId != TR.DriverId;  
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _ErrorMessage; 
            END; 
            ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM DRSLine DL INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.AWBNo=DL.AWBNo ) THEN 
            BEGIN  
                SELECT CONCAT('Box: ',  AWBNo, ' is already scanned') INTO _ErrorMessage FROM tempDRSJson; 
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _ErrorMessage;
            END; 
            ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM RunsheetDetail DRS INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.AWBNo=DRS.AWBNo LIMIT 1) THEN
            BEGIN  
                SELECT DISTINCT concat('Box already scanned in another Runsheet: ', RunsheetNo) into _ErrorMessage  FROM RunsheetDetail WHERE AWBNo = _AWBNo ; 
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _ErrorMessage; 
            END;  
            ELSE IF  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ReScheduleDetails RD INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.AWBNo=RD.AWBNo LIMIT 1) THEN
            BEGIN  
                 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='AWB has Reschedule without date.' ;
            END;   
            END IF;  
            END IF;  
            END IF; 
            END IF; 
            END IF; 
            END IF; 
                SELECT CONCAT('Runsheet created for driver: '
                , ' - ',COALESCE(cast( UM.UserId as char))) Driver
                INTO _ErrorMessage 
                FROM  DRSHeader  DH  
                INNER JOIN  UserMaster UM ON DH.DriverId = UM.Id AND UM.RoleId=1   
                INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.RunsheetNo=DH.RunsheetNo AND 
                NOT DH.DriverId=IFNULL(TR.DriverId,0) LIMIT 1 ;  
              
                IF (IFNULL(_ErrorMessage,'')!='' OR _ErrorMessage!='NULL') THEN
                BEGIN
                     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _ErrorMessage;  
                END;
                ELSE
                BEGIN    
                    
                    INSERT INTO DRSLine(RunsheetNo, ShelvingId, DriverId, AWBNo, Status, InsertedBy, InsertedOn, LocationCode) 
                    SELECT RunsheetNo, 0,  DriverId,  AWBNo, 'Shipped',  InsertedBy, NOW(), LocationCode
                    FROM tempDRSJson ;
                    
                    UPDATE  DRSHeader  DH  INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON DH.RunsheetNo = TR.RunsheetNo 
                    SET DH.DriverId =  TR.DriverId, DH.VehicleNo = TR.VehicleNo;
                     
 
                    INSERT INTO tempDRS (RunsheetNo,  DriverId, FacilityAddress,  Latitude, Longitude   ) 
                    SELECT _RunsheetNo,  _DriverId,
                    CONCAT(Address1, ', ',City)Facility, Latitude, Longitude
                    FROM LocationMaster  LIMIT 1;
                
                   INSERT INTO tempDRS (
                    Id, RunsheetNo,  AWBNo,  City
                    ,  DriverId,  DriverName ,  Status ,  DriverPhoneNo 
                    , PaymentMethod, CollectableAmount,  FacilityAddress,  PhoneNumber1 
                    ,  Consignee, ConsigneeAddress1, Latitude, Longitude, InsertedOn,  InsertedBy,LocationCode, VehicleNo  ) 
                    SELECT  
                    DL.Id, DH.RunsheetNo, DL.AWBNo, IFNULL(SD.City, '') AS City
                    , DL.DriverId, concat ( DL.DriverId ,' - ',DM.Name )as DriverName, DL.Status
                    , DM.PhoneNo as DriverPhoneNo, '' AS PaymentMethod , 0 AS CollectableAmount, '' AS FacilityAddress
                    , '' PhoneNumber1, '' Consignee
                    , concat(SD.City, ', Block: ',SD.Block, ', Street: ',SD.Street, ', Country: ', SD.Country)  ConsigneeAddress1
                    , IFNULL(SD.Latitude,'0')Latitude, IFNULL(SD.Longitude,'0')Longitude
                    , DL.InsertedOn, DH.InsertedBy, DL.LocationCode, DH.VehicleNo
                    FROM DRSHeader DH 
                    INNER JOIN  DRSLine DL ON DL.RunsheetNo = DH.RunsheetNo 
                    INNER JOIN tempDRSJson TR ON TR.RunsheetNo= DH.RunsheetNo
                    INNER JOIN UserMaster DM ON DL.DriverId = DM.Id 
                    INNER JOIN ShipmentData SD ON DL.AWBNO = SD.AWBNo 
                    ORDER BY SD.Longitude ASC;  
 
                   SELECT SRNO, Id, RunsheetNo,  AWBNo,  City
                    , Consignee,  ConsigneeAddress1, IFNULL(Latitude,0)Latitude
                    , IFNULL(Longitude,0)Longitude, PhoneNumber1 
                    , DriverId,  DriverName ,  DriverPhoneNo ,  Status 
                    , PaymentMethod, CollectableAmount,  FacilityAddress
                    , InsertedOn,  InsertedBy, LocationCode, VehicleNo  
                    FROM tempDRS   ORDER BY SRNO;  
                
                     
                
                END;
                END IF; 
            
    END;
    END IF;
      

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The the line 170 you have a single

```
set MESSAGE_TEXT ;
```

That makes at that position no sense and has the wrong syntax for `SET`

Comment: it was mistakenly added, i removed it

Comment: then you can delete the question if that was all